# Simple Moving Average for stock prices

Tags: java, moving-average

I was playing with ActiveQuant FinancialLibrary SimpleMovingAverage function SMA() below:

Is there an error in the algo below, where it calculates the average by looking "into the future" ( as it does i < (period + skipdays) ) ?

```
public static double SMA(int period, double[] vals, int skipdays) {
    double value = 0.0;
    for (int i = skipdays; i < (period + skipdays); i++) {
        value += vals[i];
    }
    value /= (double) period;
    return value;
}
```

The for loop can be replaced with that below, where it looks backward.

```
    for (int i = skipdays - period; i < skipdays; i++) {
        value += vals[i];
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: Do you have any reason to prefer one implementation to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no error.  The algorithm correctly computes the mean value of the data array from index `skipdays` (inclusive) to index `skipdays + period` (exclusive) for `period > 0`.

Perhaps you need to rephrase the question.

Comment: Yes there is no error, as ActiveQuant expects the first data or vals[0] is for the current date, vals[1] is the data for yesterday, etc. I was using it the other way around.